# vuforia AR SDK - can't play video by url

Tags: java, android, sdk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm experimenting with Vuforia augmented reality SDK and it's samples. I successfully compiled videopayback sample and ran it on my tablet. Then I tried to load the video from a url instead of from the device. 
Following the comments in the sample code, in VideoPlayerHelper.java I commented out this part:

```
// This example shows how to load the movie from the
// assets folder of the app
// However, if you would like to load the movie from the
// sdcard or from a network location
// simply comment the three lines below
AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets()
    .openFd(filename);
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
    afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
```

and commented this part and added a url to a video file online:

```
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://oneshot.qualcomm.com/webAR/content/strawberryfields_H264_AAC.mp4");
```

Still I can compile it without an error but when I point the camera towards the trigger image I either see a cross on it or an hourglass which seems to mean it is loading the video. But nothing happens. Any idea what else I should do to fix this? I looked around in vuforia forums. Most solutions said to choose the video properly(the one I'm using was suggested there) and changes that are basically what I'm already doing like doing this:

```
Uri videolink = Uri.parse("http://oneshot.qualcomm.com/webAR/content/strawberryfields_H264_AAC.mp4");
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mParentActivity,videolink);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem after doing those changes mentioned in your question. However, in **VideoPlayerHelper.java**, I just commented  the AssetFileDescriptor code(3 lines)

```
//AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
//mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),  afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
//afd.close();
```

and uncommented/changed the following line  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://giftsoninternet.com/android/EngageApp/VuforiaSizzleReel_1.m4v");

I corrected this problem by commenting one line in **VideoPlayback.java** file, where video player is trying to access video from **assets/VideoPlayback** folder.

```
// mMovieName[STONES] = "VideoPlayback/VuforiaSizzleReel_1.mp4";
```

P.S. -I commented only this line because I was using only **STONES.jpg** target image for Vuforia rendering. If you are using **CHIPS**, you can comment that line instead.